# Firebase permission | Set role, block user to delete records and allow to read only certain records

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building a chat system through anonymous authentication.
There are two roles, the "moderator" role and the "visitor" role.
I therefore have three questions.

1. How can I create the two roles and associate the users?
2. How can I block the visitor role from deleting record records but only adding them?
3. How can I allow the "visitor" role to read only his messages?

My configuration is the follow:
Message -> timestamp -> Field: message, time and reference.

I use the "reference" field to understand which moderator the message is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

You can either track the user's role in the database, or in a custom claim. I typically prefer the former in scenarios like this, where the data that needs to be protected is also stored in the database already.

For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [securing attribute-based and Role-based access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
But is it possible to allow adding new records but not delete them?

I have a child "message" and I would like to avoid that a user, from the javascript console, can read all messages or delete values.

Comment: Adding vs updated: have a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data. If you're having trouble making that work, it's more likely we can help if you show what you've tried.

Comment: Hey @nicknameacaso Anything more needed here?